# How to integrate a function of a direction, over the hemisphere

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

The *Mathematica* documentation [Integrate over Regions](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/symbolic-geometry/integrate-over-regions.html) gives an example of how to simply integrate over a sphere (surface):

```
Integrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ Sphere[]]
```

<s>Although it seems there is an [Hemisphere object](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hemisphere.html) in *Mathematica*, it does not seem possible to easily integrate over all the directions that it includes.</s>

Is there an elegant way to similarly compute the integral of a function over all the directions in an hemisphere?

*An example of an application of this would be solving [rendering equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendering_equation)*

Comment: Hemisphere objects in Mathematica are geographical, not geometric region objects. Nonetheless, you can construct more complex regions and use them on `Integrate`, for instance: `Integrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ RegionIntersection[Sphere[], ImplicitRegion[x > 0, {x, y, z}]]]`, which takes the parts of the sphere surface where `x > 0`.

Comment: ... and in v10.2, you can also use `HalfSpace`.

Comment: You referenced an article about hemispheres in MathWorld. Although MathWorld is a Wolfram site, it discussed mathematics, not _Mathematica_. In particular, the hemisphere it discusses is not a built-in _Mathematica_ object.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thank you, I updated the question.

Comment: @kirma How do you use HalfSpace in an integral (over all the possible directions) ?

Comment: @wil My implied intent was that you can use `HalfSpace` instead of explicitly written `ImplicitRegion` to specify which hemisphere of `Sphere` to use. Maybe it even gets treated more efficiently as an abstraction on some future version of Mma!

Answer (score 2):

These drawing and formula can be found in the [Global Illumination Compendium (P.15)](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~philip.dutre/GI/TotalCompendium.pdf#page=15):

[image: Hemisphere parametrization]

The integral can therefore be computed as:

```
Integrate[f[φ, θ] Sin[θ], {φ,0,2π}, {θ, 0, π/2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

One can do it changing the integrand:

```
Integrate[1 Boole[x > 0], {x, y, z} ∈ Sphere[]]
```

Comment: Or one can specify the domain completely as a region, just as kirma indicates in the comments to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Just realized this was in the comments already, but here it is written explicitly:

You can construct the region yourself, e.g.

```
hemisphere = RegionIntersection[Sphere[],HalfSpace[{-1,0,0},0]];
```

Then the following will work:

```
Integrate[1,{x,y,z}\[Element] hemisphere]
```